# Flink Table Api to Deploy job Remote Flink Server

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have a Flink server running on a computer.
I want to create a java web app, which can deploy SQLs(Source create sql.., Sink create SQL.... and Insert into Sink select field1, ... from source table)

I understand that Table API can be used to execute SQL. But my Questions are

1. How can I execute the above SQLs to Remote Flink Server using Table API.
2. When used *RemoteStreamEnvironment* , the application shows error of missing jars which are already available in Flink's /lib folder (flink-connector-kafka-1.15.2.jar, kafka-clients-3.1.0.jar, flink-table-common-1.15.2.jar)

When I am instantiating the **RemoteStreamEnvironment** as below it works *StreamExecutionEnvironment remoteStreamEnvironment = RemoteStreamEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment(flinkCluster, flinkClusterPort, user_Dir + "/flink-connector-kafka-1.15.2.jar", user_Dir + "/kafka-clients-3.1.0.jar", user_Dir + "/flink-table-common-1.15.2.jar");*

What is the mistake I am doing here? when the third parameters are removed by adding these jars to Flink's lib folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check out the SQL Gateway that will become available with Flink 1.16. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sql-gateway/overview/